# SCORM packages in Moodle - how to debug errors

Tags: javascript, debugging, moodle, scorm

I am trying to get SCORM packages to work correctly in my Moodle 2.7.11 site.

I am getting a couple of different errors while using the SCORM, such as:

```
LMSSetValue Error: cmi.core.lesson_location to [page242.html] Not initialized.
```

-

```
LMSSetValue Error: cmi.suspenddata to [----] Not initialized.
```

-

```
Some of the persistent data was not able to be stored.
```

-

```
LMSSetValue Error: cmi.core.lesson_status to [passed] Not initialized.
```

-

```
LMSCommit Error: Not initialized.
```

I have tested the Scorm packages and verified that they work on ScormCloud (a scorm testing site).

It seems like there must be some incompatibility between: i) The SCORM standard the The Scorm module was built for, ii) The jquery version, or iii) the SCORM version that this version of Moodle supports.

I have turned on the option for debugging Scorm modules (in Site Admin/plugins/activities/Scorm) but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm not sure where these debug messages are sent. There are some Moodle docs for this but they don't tell you where to find the debug log, https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/SCORM_FAQ#Debugging.

UPDATE:

Here is the debugging when I run one of the SCORM courses on SCORM cloud:

```
[17:21:56.925] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity CourseID -org
[17:21:56.925] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity CourseID -org
[17:21:56.925] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity I_A001
+ [17:22:00.197] LMSInitialize('') returned 'true' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:00.198] LMSGetValue('cmi.core.lesson_status') returned 'not attempted' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:00.199] LMSSetValue('cmi.core.lesson_status', 'incomplete') returned 'true' in 0.007 seconds
+ [17:22:00.206] LMSCommit('') returned 'true' in 0 seconds
  [17:22:00.355] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity CourseID -org
  [17:22:00.355] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity CourseID -org
  [17:22:00.355] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity I_A001
+ [17:22:00.731] LMSGetValue('cmi.core.lesson_location') returned '' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:00.732] LMSSetValue('cmi.core.lesson_location', 'page44294.html') returned 'true' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:08.411] LMSSetValue('cmi.core.lesson_location', 'page37662.html') returned 'true' in 0.004 seconds
+ [17:22:08.471] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned '' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:08.471] LMSSetValue('cmi.suspend_data', ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;') returned 'true' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:08.472] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:08.472] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:08.473] LMSSetValue('cmi.suspend_data', ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;') returned 'true' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:08.473] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:10.247] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:10.248] LMSSetValue('cmi.suspend_data', ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;') returned 'true' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:10.249] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:10.250] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:10.251] LMSSetValue('cmi.suspend_data', ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;') returned 'true' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:10.252] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:16.545] LMSSetValue('cmi.core.lesson_location', 'page41883.html') returned 'true' in 0.004 seconds
+ [17:22:17.573] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;' in 0.002 seconds
+ [17:22:17.576] LMSSetValue('cmi.suspend_data', ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;') returned 'true' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:17.577] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:17.578] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:17.579] LMSSetValue('cmi.suspend_data', ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;') returned 'true' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:17.580] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:17.582] LMSSetValue('cmi.core.score.raw', '0') returned 'true' in 0.002 seconds
+ [17:22:17.585] LMSCommit('') returned 'true' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:17.616] LMSSetValue('cmi.core.lesson_status', 'failed') returned 'true' in 0.005 seconds
+ [17:22:17.622] LMSCommit('') returned 'true' in 0 seconds
    [17:22:17.736] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity CourseID -org
    [17:22:17.737] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity CourseID -org
    [17:22:17.737] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity I_A001
    [17:22:17.911] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity CourseID -org
    [17:22:17.911] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity CourseID -org
    [17:22:17.911] Beginning prerequisites evaluation of activity I_A001
+ [17:22:19.399] LMSSetValue('cmi.core.session_time', '00:00:19') returned 'true' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:19.400] LMSCommit('') returned 'true' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:20.174] LMSSetValue('cmi.core.lesson_location', 'page37991.html') returned 'true' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:23.223] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;' in 0.002 seconds
+ [17:22:23.225] LMSSetValue('cmi.suspend_data', ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;') returned 'true' in 0.003 seconds
+ [17:22:23.228] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:23.229] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:23.229] LMSSetValue('cmi.suspend_data', ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;') returned 'true' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:23.229] LMSGetValue('cmi.suspend_data') returned ';~;Kunskapstest_Prov_Score=0;Kunskapstest_Score=0;' in 0 seconds
+ [17:22:36.518] OverallSequencingProcess for SCORM 1.1 / SCORM 1.2 returned '' in 2.216 seconds
+ [17:22:36.574] LMSSetValue('cmi.core.session_time', '00:00:36') returned 'true' in 0.002 seconds
+ [17:22:36.576] LMSCommit('') returned 'true' in 0.001 seconds
+ [17:22:36.577] LMSFinish('') returned 'true' in 0.002 seconds
+ [17:22:36.578] Pre-evaluation of exit action
+ [17:22:38.735] OverallSequencingProcess for SCORM 1.1 / SCORM 1.2
```

This is how it came out when I ran it on SCORM cloud but I don't think that it always does this in this order. That's why I want to be able to debug within Moodle to find out what has gone wrong when an error appears.

Comment: Can you post the debug log from scorn cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a multi-SCO course?  I have seen this in some courses if it calls LMSFinish in a SCO, then never re-initializes when it launches the next SCO.  The debug log from SCORM Cloud can definitely light a path for us here if you share it.

In order to share it here, you can take the course in the SCORM Cloud sandbox, then once you exit, scroll down to the debug section.  Click on the link for the session where you took the course, this should open the debug log...scroll all the way to the bottom of the log, there should be an URL you can copy and paste here to share.

Thank you!

Joe

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have tried to replicate the issue by launching several SCORM courses simultaneously but that seems to run fine (the errors that do occur are sporadic). I am mainly interested in working out how Moodle's SCORM debugging feature works so that I can trace what happens when there is a problem while using the SCORM courses within Moodle. I just added the Scorm cloud debugging to the question - but, as noted, it looks like the SCORM works ok there.

Comment: I know it's not quite what you're asking, but you can also debug from the course side. It appears your SCORM session is not initialized; you can add console.log code to your course's SCORM calls to track whether or not the initialization succeeded. Add a console statement to your course's `LMSInitialize()` routine, such as `result = API.LMSInitialize(""); console.log("init: " + result);`

Answer (score 1):

The moodle scorm debug info should appear as a popup the second the course launches, make sure your browser isn't blocking the window from opening.